# Templates, arrays and constant expressions

Tags: c++, templates, constant-expression, template-argument-deduction

Consider the code below:

```
template<char>
struct S { }; 

template<int N>
constexpr auto f(const char (&ref) [N]) {
    return S<ref[0]>{};
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto v = f("foo");
    (void)v;
}
```

It doesn't compile for `ref[0]` is not a constant expression.

Anyway, the code below compiles fine:

```
template<int N>
constexpr auto f(const char (&ref) [N]) {
    return ref[0];
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto v = f("foo");
    (void)v;
}
```

Should both of them compile or fail to do that for more or less the same reason?

From [[expr.const]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) we have that:

> A conditional-expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e` [...] would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>   [...]
>   - an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>       - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>       - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

Anyway, in this case, it is initialized with a constant expression **and** the lifetime is the same of `e`, thus the rule doesn't apply.

What's wrong in my reasoning?

As a side question, I would ask if it's possible to use such an array or part of it as a template argument.

Comment: Note that a constexpr function can still be called at runtime, and `S<ref[0]>` cannot be instantiated at runtime.

Comment: @kennytm Note that I'm calling it as `constexpr auto v = f("foo");`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, someone else could call it as `char a[10]; randomize(a); f(a)`.

Comment: @kennytm I see your point. No chance thus to use it as a template parameter?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in general case but if you are using g++ you could make use of its extension in [string literal](https://godbolt.org/g/ffMXRu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
template<int N>
constexpr auto f(const char (&ref) [N]) {
    return S<ref[0]>{};
}
```

is ill-formed because according to [temp.arg.nontype]:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of
>   the type of the *template-parameter*.

and from [expr.const]:

> A *conditional-expression* e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions: [...]
>   (2.7) — an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>   (2.7.1) — a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const
>   object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
>   (2.7.2) — a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a subobject of a string literal (2.13.5), or
>   (2.7.3) — a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr, or that refers to
>   a non-mutable sub-object of such an object, or
>   (2.7.4) — a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within
>   the evaluation of e;

`ref[0]` requires an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and none of those sub-bullets apply. Note that `ref` is not a string literal, so 2.7.2 doesn't apply, nor is it defined with `constexpr`, because it's a function argument and we don't have that capability.

We basically need the ability to pass string literals *as literals*, which doesn't exist yet.

---

The other example:

```
template<int N>
constexpr auto f(const char (&ref) [N]) {
    return ref[0];
}
```

doesn't have the converted constant expression required - that one was brought in by the template non-type argument. This code is fine, and would only be problematic if you tried to initialize a `constexpr` variable with a non-`constexpr` array value.

Answer (score 0):

The first example shouldn't compile because you cannot have compiletime-only constexpr functions (or overload on compiletime-ness, like D's [`__cfte`](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#interpretation)).

Following this reasoning, if you called first example's `f` at runtime, what would its return type be?

As to the side question: Boost Hana, despite supporting only the newest standard, only uses string literals for runtime stuff, so it may not be possible.